# Treat multiple elements as one

Tags: jquery, html

I have a script that counts the number of items in an unordered list, and splits the items to create two seperate lists, however the site this script runs on is changing a lot of its lists to definition lists with a single `<dt>` and `<dd>` element per item. Is there a way to find the `<dt>` and its child `<dd>` and treat them as a single element. So i can find and count each row

```
<dl>
  <dt>Title 1</dt><dd>Item 1</dd>
  <dt>Title 2</dt><dd>Item 2</dd>
</dl>
```

as a single entity?

**EDIT**

this is the current script that works for my list items at present, as some indication towards what im trying to achieve.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
    var $bigList = $('#bigList'),
    number = Math.round(($("li").size())/2),
    group;

    while((group = $bigList.find('li:lt(' + number + ')').remove()).length){
    $('<ul/>').append(group).appendTo('body');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: First off, <dd> is not a child of <dt>. <dd> is outside of <dt>

Comment: Assuming every item in your list is in that format, why don't you simply count the number of `dd` or `dt` elements?

Comment: yea i know sorry i didnt mean it as a direct child, as in for each <dt> element there is a single <dd> element after it. Bad wording, shouldnt haven't used child sorry.

Comment: Mind posting the existing script?

Comment: The way the old script works is it broke up each <li> and replaced them in order, so i can count either the <dd> or the <dt> no problem, but when i break up the list and re build it doesnt match the <dd> up with the respective <dt>, hence trying to find a way as treating each pair as a single unit.

Comment: @Michael sure thing, one sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below, I suppose. You might want to fiddle with the slice function to get the last half rather than the first half and maybe change the ceil to a floor (round down instead of up) but it's a good starting point.

```
$('#list2').append(
    $("#list1 > *").slice(0,
       Math.ceil($('#list1 dt').length/2) * 2
    )
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uKmJn/4/

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with the appropriate selector:

```
$("dt + dd").length
```

Note though, that you only select every `dd` who follow a `dt`. So this is good for counting, but it won't do what you expect if you're trying to apply style or animate the `dt` and `dd`. But then, just do another selection for this other use case.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to count particular tag inside the `dl` i.e. either `dt` or `dd` using `getElementsByTagName()`.

Use the following:

```
<dl id=dl1>
  <dt>Title 1</dt><dd>Item 1</dd>
  <dt>Title 2</dt><dd>Item 2</dd>
  <dt>Title 3</dt><dd>Item 3</dd>
  <dt>Title 4</dt><dd>Item 4</dd>
</dl>
<button onClick="alert(document.getElementById('dl1').getElementsByTagName('dt').length);">count_items</button>
```

Check this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G2wxn/)**